# Vagrant: How can you run scripts on the host via commands in the guest shell?

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, atom-editor, vagrant-plugin

It's possible to open ports, network files, and there are plug-ins that allow for running guest or host [shell] commands during Vagrant's Provisioning process.

What I'd like to do is be able to (perhaps through a bash alias) run a command in the Vagrant guest/VM, and have this execute a command on the host, ideally with a variable being passed on the command line.

Example: In my host I run the Atom editor (same applies to TextMate, whatever).  If I want to work on a shared file in the VM, I have to manually open that file from over in the host, either by opening it directly in the editor, or running the 'atom filename' shell command.

I want parity, so while inside the VM, I can run 'atom filename', and this will pass the filename to the 'atom $1' script outside of the VM, in the host, and open it in my host editor (Atom).

---

Note: We use Salt for Vagrant Provisioning, and NFS for mounting, for what it's worth.  And of course, ssh with key.

Bonus question: Making this work with .gitconfig as its merge conflict editor (should just work, if the former is possible, right?).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting use case that I haven't heard before. There isn't a native method of handling this in Vagrant, but this functionality was added to Packer in the form of a [local shell provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell-local.html). You could open a GitHub issue on the [Vagrant project](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant) and propose the same feature. Double check the current list of issues, though, because it's possible someone has beaten you to it.

In the meantime, though, you do have a workaround if you're determined to do this...

1. Create an ssh key pair on your host.
2. Use Salt to add the private key in `/home/vagrant/.ssh` on the box.
3. Use a shell provisioner to run remote ssh commands on the host from the guest.

These commands would take the form of...

```
ssh username@192.168.0.1 "ls -l ~"
```

In my experience, the `192.168.0.1` IP always points back to the host, but your mileage may vary. I'm not a networking expert by any means.

I hope this works for you and I think a local shell provisioner for Vagrant would be a reasonable feature.